# how to select options from dropdown box using jmeter

Tags: drop-down-menu, jmeter

I have one dropdown box in my application it has 4 options like A10,cisco,ctrix and F5. I want to select F5 every time and I need fill some details regarding F5.
Can anyone please help me

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to select this value in the drop down, so that you can later submit this form. If the drop down is in a vanilla html form, then the two steps: of choosing values for the form inputs (including this drop down); and of submitting the form; result in one request to the http server. And that's what your jmeter script should perform. A second request, with the target url set to the target url of the html form; the method set to POST or GET, depending on the form; and the http parameters populated with key-value pairs with keys set to names of the inputs in the html source and values corresponding to what you would like to select in the inputs in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add an HTTP request with parameters for each form element you want to submit.  The "Name" and "Value" should exactly match the form fields (use developer tools to check what is actually submitted)
Something like this:
[image]